# Two way binding for ng-click directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click, two-way-binding

I have calling a function in two elements. when I triggering the function an on-click event then also it should be hit once more time for wherever I called that function.

//html

```
<button type="button" ng-click="{{myFunction()}}">click Me !!</button>
  <p ng-show="{{myFunction()}}">{{name}}</p>
```

//controller

```
myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Helow World!';
  $scope.myFunction = function(){
    return true;
  };
});
```

I also tried with `""` instead of `{{}}` for *two way binding*

```
  <button type="button" ng-click="myFunction()">click Me !!</button>
  <p ng-show="myFunction()">{{name}}</p>
```

### Problem :

The function will be firing only one time. Show my `p` tag does not show.

### Solution

I can use a scope object to `Show|hide` the `p` tag. But that's not my question.

### Question

My question is, how to implement Two way binding for `event(ng-click)` same as works like `ng-repeat,ng-model,mg-show,etc` in angularjs?

Comment: are you getting any error in console?what kind of result you want?

Comment: The function will be firing only one time. Show my `p` tag does not show.

Comment: 2. html will work you are wrong. And what do you mean with event two way binding ? what are you wanting to do ?

Comment: @TejinderSingh . I have update my question.

Comment: ng-click event is a function not a variable so there will be no two way binding

Comment: But I have assign the function in a variable : `$scope.myFunction =Function()....`

Comment: What you expect to happen when function has 'two way binding' ?

Comment: it automatically calls the function on `ng-show` and it will always happen.What exactly you want to do?

Comment: i think you need to give one more variable for `ng-show` and set it true within `myFunction()`. right now what happen is when  `myFunction()` returns it also sets `ng-click` as true. so the  `myFunction()`  method is gone. then it was something like `<button type="button" ng-click="true">click Me !!</button>`

Comment: If you mention a function in ng-show, it will get evaluated in the background at the runtime. This is termed as a two-way binding.  What you are trying to accomplish is not gonna happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going about this wrong.

The angular directives work with angular expressions, that means that whatever you insert into e.g. `ng-show` is executed using `$parse(expr)($scope)` - that's the short version. So if your expression contains a function call, that function is called whenever the directive decides to execute the expression. In the case of `ng-show`, that happens on every digest cycle. in the case of `ng-click` that happens on the click event.

So when you use code like this: `ng-show="myFunc()"` and your function is defined like this:

```
$scope.myFunc = function() { return true; };
```

then on every digest, this function is executed and returns `true` to the ng-show. It doesn't have anything to do with what is going on in the `ng-click` directive.

What you're asking can't be done. Angular just doesn't work that way. The solution you state with

> I can use a scope object to Show|hide the p tag. But that's not my question.

is your best and only option.